# Not able to download docker image in service fabric cluster

Tags: azure, docker

I have created one service fabric application to deploy docker image on service fabric. I am successfully able to deploy application on the service image but not able to download docker image from azure container registry.

Below error i am getting:
**Container image download failed with authorization attempt type ClusterManifestDefaultCredentials**

Policies in ApplicationManifest.xml looks like this:

```
   <Policies>
      <ContainerHostPolicies CodePackageRef="Code" UseDefaultRepositoryCredentials="true">
        <!-- See https://aka.ms/I7z0p9 for how to encrypt your repository password -->
        <RepositoryCredentials AccountName="<reg-name>" Password="<pass>" PasswordEncrypted="false" />
        <PortBinding ContainerPort="8888" EndpointRef="Guest_Container1TypeEndpoint" />
      </ContainerHostPolicies>
    </Policies>
```

Comment: did you consult the link: https://aka.ms/I7z0p9 ?

Comment: What the account name and password do you use?

Comment: Try to delete the property `UseDefaultRepositoryCredentials="true"`. Then take a look at [`UseDefaultRepositoryCredentials`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started-containers#configure-cluster-wide-credentials).